# Content in header section overflows Navbar and goes out of view when minimizing browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [this](https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-new-age) Theme available on Github. [Here](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-new-age/) you can view it online.

I want to stop the content inside `<header> </header>` section from overflowing the navbar and going outside of the browser view. (See attached picture).

The header-section should be resized correctly, when I resize the browser.
I have tried to use `display: flex;` instead of `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`, but I had no success. Then I tried `height: (100vh + 50px);` which seems to work a bit better, but I'm not sure if that is a good approach?

Could someone show me which parts are important to stop the header-section from overflowing and going out of view?

```
header .header-content {
   padding: 150px 0 50px;
   position: relative;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
   header {
      min-height: 100%;
}
   header .header-content {
      text-align: left;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
       max-width: none;
       margin: 0;
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       transform: translateY(-50%);
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Upon viewing your webpage, the header looks fine. It does not overflow in any way, in different sizes it works well. Not sure what your question is

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please resize your browser vertically to a small window (like in my picture). While resizing the browser you will see the text from the header section is moving behind the navbar and going out of view on top.